# Zend Framework and Apache

Tags: apache, zend-framework

Most of the Zend framework books talk about using the framework with the Zend Server.
Is it possible to use Apache instead and if so is there any major drawback?

Comment: Zend Server uses Apache as well (on windows)... so the question is a bit odd. AND of course you can run any php website with Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I suppose the drawback could be that the Web Server is not automatically configured for you, if you don't use a WAMP/LAMP stack like Zend Server.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use it with Apache, the only drawback is that you have to configure your environment in order to make ZF work and also to clarify things out Zend Server is an application server not a web server you can think of it as a LAMP stack but you can also choose IIS if your on windows.